# Is currentWindow still there? Results from chrome.tabs.query are empty

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am using chromium "Version 75.0.3770.90 (Official Build)" and trying to develop an extension. I have a lot done, but I'm stuck trying to work on this one piece that requires me to know the current tab/window that is open.

I am trying to use the function below as described by the google docs as well as everyone else I see that needs the same info.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},console.log)
```

But, the response I get is
    undefined

If I remove `currentWindow:true` I get an array containing two objects because I have two windows open.

This also results in an array with two objects as well.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,discarded:false},console.log)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: It means your active window doesn't have any tabs. For example it can be a devtools window.